# Specify rest arguments first in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, rest-parameters

I have a function which receives a variable number of arguments (each of type string), and a final argument (of a complex type, called Expression).

In JavaScript, this looks like:

```
function layerProp(...args) {
  const fields = args.slice(0, -1)
  const fallbackExpression = args.slice(-1)[0]
```

How can I write a type definition for this function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following type:

```
function layerProp(...args: [...string[], Expression]) {}
```

However, it won't type the `slice` and the easiest solution would be just to assert the last element to `Expression` as follows:

```
function layerProp(...args: [...string[], Expression]) {
  const fields = args.slice(0, -1);
  const fallbackExpression = args.slice(-1)[0] as Expression;
}
```

Usage:

```
type Expression = {
  a: string;
}

layerProp('a', 'b', 'c', { a: 'sd' });
layerProp('a', 'b', 'c', { a: 'sd' }, 'a'); // expected error
layerProp('a', 'b', 'c', 'a'); // expected error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHmAThAziglgewHZQLxQDeAUFFAIYBcUKwi62A5gNzEC+xxAZgK7YDGwLLgA25EBEQAFRJjAAKAHTLyiRimoBtZYtr0mmgLoAaWAmRphhgJRFSUfjlpQu6CCIAmKfBTUpdIuj8EPIADKYAtACM1qxkjtjOXOQiIgBG5PwA1vBIqBg4PqrqAUEh0daaoYYU3rkWBdisHMRiEtKyCgDk5F2mXWl9UF38Q4QU1F0oHl1QbLGt4pIycvI9QwMbo6bjVMPTs2z9vbFQAPRnUBAIEIIQHleIsoiL7Svdvf2D-dvDJ8znS7XSB3B6SZ7EIA)

Answer (score 0):

For the function argument you can write as `...args: string[]`, From the function implementation `fallbackExpression` is a simple string. So it would be better to use a interface instead of a type

```js
function layerProp(...args: string[]) {
  const fields = args.slice(0, -1)
  const fallbackExpression = args.slice(-1)[0]
  // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: But the last element of the array isn't a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a union type like:

```
(string | Expression)[]
```

Then your code becomes:

```
function layerProp(...args: (string | Expression)[]) {
  const fields = args.slice(0, -1)
  const fallbackExpression = args.slice(-1)[0]
  // rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your method gets one complex `Expression` object, and a bunch of strings, you might want to consider flipping the positions of the arguments, and then you can do this:

```js
function layerProp(expression: Expression, ...fields: strings[]) {
  // ... your code
}
```

Comment: Yes, obviously that's a workaround. But is there an actual solution?

Comment: It all depends on the implementation and what you are trying to achieve. In my personal opinion, if you really have only one `Expression` and a lot of strings. This is the way I wrote write it, and I would consider this the better solution, and not just a workaround. Of course, it all depends on the needed solution

Comment: I guess another to go about it would be to make the `layerProp` method get an object of type `Data`, which includes `expression: Expression` and `fields: strings[]`. which would allow you to define default object for expression case not provided, while still enforcing the fields if not provided

Comment: I think an actual solution to the way you describe it in your question is not really available, specially if the number of string array is varied. If the method is supposed to accept one Express and an `n` amount of strings, there is currently no way to define just the last element of the array